# Converting Firebase Token to String using Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an application that is supposed to send the Firebase Token from my Flutter app to an ASP.Net App Server. The endpoint on the app server works - the request from the Flutter app to the App Server is not working.

The reason it is not working is because when I try to send the token, the token doesn't appear to have arrived yet - it's of type Future. How do I turn that token into a string when it finally arrives?

I've tried turning the token directly into a string in the fcmStream.Listen function, I've also tried turning it into a string using _firebaseMessaging.getToken. Neither of them work

```
  FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = new FirebaseMessaging();

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    location.onLocationChanged().listen((value) {
      if (this.mounted) {
        setState(() {
          currentLocation = value;
        });
      }
    });
_firebaseMessaging.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
        print('on message $message');
      },
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
        print('on resume $message');
      },
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
        print('on launch $message');
      },
    );
    _firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions(
        const IosNotificationSettings(sound: true, badge: true, alert: true));
    String clientToken = _firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((token) {
      print("Token Init: " + token.toString());
    }
    ).toString();


    BackendService.postToken(clientToken.toString(), "email@gmail.com");

    @override
    Stream<String> fcmStream = _firebaseMessaging.onTokenRefresh;
    fcmStream.listen((token) {
      /*print("Token On Refresh: " + token);
      BackendService.postToken(token.toString(), "email@gmail.com");*/

    }
    );
    fcmStream.toString();

class BackendService {
  static Future<String> postToken(String token, String hostEmail) async {
    final responseBody = (await http.get(
            'realurlomitted/.../Meets/RegisterDevice?token=$token&hostEmail=$hostEmail')).body;
    print(" Response: " + responseBody.toString());

    return responseBody.toString();
  }
}
```

Whenever the token.toString prints, it prints the token just fine - I can see that. It just seems like whenever it tries to make the post using http, the token hasn't arrived from whatever getToken is.

If I can turn that Futrure into a string by awaiting it or something, it would solve my problem so that the $token parameter is the token as a string.

More specifically, my request URL should look like:

```
https://-----/Meets/RegisterDevice?token=c6V49umapn0:Jdsf90832094890s324&hostEmail=email@gmail.com
```

But it looks like:

```
https://-----/Meets/RegisterDevice?token=instance of Future<Dynamic>&hostEmail=email@gmail.com
```

In the Flutter debugger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, awaiting the future will solve your problem. You can write an `async` function and put the code in your `initState` inside it and use `await`, or you can do this:

```
_firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((token) {
      final tokenStr = token.toString();
      // do whatever you want with the token here
    }
);
```

Comment: This caused me an uncomfortable amount of trouble - I definitely lack a fundamental understanding of the language. Thank you so much! I know it's out of the scope of the question, but why is it that final will wait for the token to be determined like an async method would?

Comment: @kalittles `final` doesn't have anything to do with this. you can use `var` or `String` if you want. I used `token` inside `then()`, `then()` waits for the async operation to finish before executing the code.

Comment: @kalittles [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SmTCmDMi4BY) will help you understand

Answer (score 0):

This style is now available

```
FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then((user) {
            if (user != null) {
              user.getIdToken().then((token) {
                Map<dynamic,dynamic> tokenMap = token.claims;
                print(tokenMap['sub']);
              });
            }
    });
```

so this complete code

```
 @override
  void initState() {


      FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then((user) {
            if (user != null) {
              user.getIdToken().then((token) {
                Map<dynamic,dynamic> tokenMap = token.claims;
                print(tokenMap['sub']);
              });
            }
    });
    super.initState();
  }
```